# How get the date in full string format in mvc code first approach?

Tags: c#, .net, date, model-view-controller, date-format

I am new to MVC Code first and I was learning it by creating a sample MVC Code First CRUD Application.

Here, currently I am getting date in this format **12/16/2019 12:00:00 AM**, but I am trying to display the date in **16th December 2019** format. How can I do this?

This is all I have in a class:

```html
public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MovieName { get; set; }
        public string GenreName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ReleasedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT:

This is my View:

```
@model VidlyApp.Models.Movie

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Details";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }

 <div class="col-lg-3">
      <h4><strong>Released Date: </strong> @Model.ReleasedDate</h4>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3">
 <h4><strong>Added Date: </strong>@Model.DateAdded</h4>
 </div>
```

I have added the  [DataType(DataType.Date)] Data Annotations, but doesn't seem to work.

What could be the possible solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you displaying the date.A date is stored in an internal format; display then formats that as required/specified. Your annotations won't change that.

Comment: @PeterSmith, I am displaying the date in Details Page. Let me update my View of Details.cshtml as well.

Comment: @OleV.V. I think you have not read my concern properly. I had mentioned that I am new to MVC Code first, and in tags I have mentioned model-view-controller. So obviously it would be MVC. Why did you down-vote?!

Comment: Model-view-controller is an architectural pattern, not a language and not a platform. I had not understood which language you are using. Not being clear about this IMO deserves a downvote (you guessed correctly, that was me). After the C# tag has been added, I have removed my downvote and voted to reopen.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the display components `@Model.ReleasedDate` and `@Model.DateAdded` to specify the display format you require. Try

```
@Model.ReleasedDate.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

See [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) for definitions and examples.

Comment: In that case, he should use dateTime.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"), with 4 "M" to full moth name.

Comment: @OleV.V. No problem, can you undo it please. Ta